# how to pass a function to a tag that uses runat server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a function using <% %>, but I got an error

```
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Source Error:
```

and that's the line

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="myCheckBox" tag="check1" Text=<% MyFunction("text"); %>/>
```

I tried wrapping on "" as I saw on another question but It just printed the function name

Comment: when are you wanting to call the function? You can do it from code behind perhaps on page load? : Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myFunc", "MyFunction();", true);

Comment: @JobesK it can ben on page load, but on this way, will I be able to set the text value?

Comment: yes pass it in the function as a param or just grab it in the function,   var myText = form.getElementById('yourID');  myText = whatever u want to set here